# need to pipe between menu items in drupal (non-css)

Tags: drupal-6, menu, hook

(Newbie)

How can I locate the PHP code which generates html for the menu in drupal 6?
Is there a hook that I could customize?
I wish to add pipe symbol between the items.
I can add this using CSS but that is not what I want.

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Vikas

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to write your own theme_menu_item().
It is documented here: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/theme_menu_item/6